# How can I specify required text and have that text show up in regex matches?

Tags: python, regex

I've been experimenting with making a simple Python web crawler, and I'm using regular expressions to find the relevant links. The site I am experimenting with is a wiki, and I want to find only the links whose URLs start with /wiki/. I may expand this to some other parts of the site as well, and so I require my code to be as dynamic as possible.

The currently regex I'm using is

```
<a\s+href=[\'"]\/wiki\/(.*?)[\'"].*?>
```

However, the matches it finds do NOT include /wiki/ in them. I was unaware of this property of regular expressions. Ideally, since I may expand this to other parts of the site (eg. /bio/), I would like the regex to return "/wiki/[rest_of_url]" rather than simply "/[rest_of_url". The regex

```
<a\s+href=[\'|"]\/(.*?)[\'"].*?>
```

works fine (it finds URLs that start with /) because it returns "/wiki/[rest_of_url]", but it does not ensure that /wiki appears in the text.

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Daniel Moniz

Comment: The obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I don't see why the first one doesn't work, but you can try simplifying it to <a[^>]+href=['"]?(/wiki/[^'">]+). You should really consider using one of the html parsers out there (Beautiful Soup for example)

Comment: Can you post your code? Also, are you using `re.match`? Maybe you need to be using `re.search` or `re.findall`.

Comment: Ah, now I see. If you want the regex to return /wiki/...stuff.., you need to expand your parentheses to include the /wiki/ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the parentheses so that they include the `/wiki/` portion of your regex

```
    <a\s+href=[\'"](\/wiki\/.*?)[\'"].*?>
```

**Edit**

In *re*, parentheses allow you to break up your search results into sections. You're telling the *re* parser to find the entire expression, but only return the portion in parentheses. You can also use multiple sets of parentheses:

```
    <a\s+href=[\'"](\/wiki\/)(.*?)[\'"].*?>
```

In this case, `MatchObject.group()` will return the entire matched object. If you call `MatchObject.groups()` however, it will return a tuple containing `/wiki/` and whatever matches the contents of the second parentheses. Check out the python.org documentation on [regex syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Hi Joel. This does seem to work, but I'm not exactly sure why. Could you please explain?

Comment: Thanks! I did not know this about regular expressions, and tutorials on them are brutal.

Comment: @Paragon: Agreed. Most of the regular expressions tutorials I've seen are not very helpful. I've found Google's [python re tutorial](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html) to be halfway decent, however.

Comment: @Paragon: You could read [Mastering Regular Expressions book by Jeffrey Friedl](http://regex.info/) to use regexs efficiently in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a HTML parser e.g. [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links):

```
from lxml import html

for element, attribute, link, pos in html.iterlinks(html_string):
    if attribute == 'href' and link.startswith('/wiki'):
       print(link)
```

Or using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29):

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
for a in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile(r'^/wiki')):
    print(a['href'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I should definitely be using this. In the meantime, however, the other answer satisfies my immediate needs.